# How to make integration tests for Hangfire RecurringJob?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, xunit, hangfire

I'm making a simple shop and I want to cancel orders that aren't grabbed. I'm using Hangfire for it and it's working! But I cannot test it properly. On the Hangfire docs, they don't mention anything about testing recurring job.

Note: I'm using `WebApplicationFactory` and `InMemoryDatabse`.

I have that simple add for the recurring job.

```cs
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(CancelNotGrabbedOrderName, () => CancelNotGrabbedOrder(), Cron.Daily);
```

and my simple test

```cs
[Fact]
public async void CancelNotGrabbedOrder_ShouldCancelOrder() {
    // Arrange:
    using var scope  = _factory.Services.CreateScope();
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<GrabGoContext>();
    var hangfireApp = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<HangfireApp>();
    var orderTakeawayTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-1);
    var addedOrder = await context.Orders.AddAsync(new Order { 
        OrderTakeawayTime = orderTakeawayTime, 
        Status = OrderStatus.ReadyToGrab,
        PickupCode = 2202,
        BuyerID = 1
    });
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    //Act:
    RecurringJob.Trigger(HangfireApp.CancelNotGrabbedOrderName);
    // Quite sad delay
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    // Assert
    var getResponse = await _adminClient.GetAsync($"api/order/{addedOrder.Entity.Id}");
    getResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode.Should().BeTrue();
    var order = await getResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<Order>();
    order.Should().NotBeNull();
    order.Status.Should().Be(OrderStatus.NotGrabbed);
    order.PickupCode.Should().BeNull();
}
```

I've also noticed that even after delay 10s and making sure that method `CancelNotGrabbedOrder()` (by debugging) is executed before `var order = await context2.Orders.SingleOrDefaultAsync(o => o.Id == addedOrder.Entity.Id);` still `context` is getting the old (not updated) order information. Maybe this is scope fault?

@Update That error from above (scope error) was occurring because of missing foreign key.

Anyway... How can I test Hangfire recurring job? Or maybe I can somehow wait for recurring job to finish? I don't want to wait 1s or so.

Comment: Could you split this test into 2 - one to check that Hangfire triggers you job and second test to test that orders were cancelled?

Comment: How can I check if hangfire triggers it other than triggering it manually? Also, test are asynchronous so it would be a problem.